# Set a datasource without a dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, twain

I need to let the user select a scanner from a custom listbox.
After selecting a scanner the user can select a button to begin the scanning process.

When I use my own method to do this `SetDataSource`, I get an "access violation"

```
public bool SetDataSource(string id)
{
    //check first scanner
    TwRc rc = DSMident(_appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDg.Control, TwDat.Identity, TwMsg.GetFirst, _srcds);

    if (_srcds.Id.ToString() == id)
    {
        return true;
    }
    rc = TwRc.Success;

    //check other scanners
    while (rc == TwRc.Success)
    {
         rc = DSMident(_appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDg.Control, TwDat.Identity, TwMsg.GetNext, _srcds);

         if (_srcds.Id.ToString() == id)
         {
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }

 public void Acquire()
 {
     TwRC rc;
     CloseSrc();
     if (appid.Id == IntPtr.Zero)
     {
         Init(hwnd);
         if (appid.Id == IntPtr.Zero)
             return;
     }
     rc = DSMident(appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Identity, TwMSG.OpenDS, srcds);
     if (rc != TwRC.Success)
         return;

     TwCapability cap = new TwCapability(TwCap.XferCount, 1);
     rc = DScap(appid, srcds, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Capability, TwMSG.Set, cap);
     if (rc != TwRC.Success)
     {
         CloseSrc();
         return;
     }

     TwUserInterface guif = new TwUserInterface();
     guif.ShowUI = 0;
     guif.ModalUI = 0;
     guif.ParentHand = hwnd;
     rc = DSuserif(appid, srcds, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.UserInterface, TwMSG.EnableDS, guif);
     if (rc != TwRC.Success)
     {
         CloseSrc();
         return;
     }
}
```

The normal way to select a datasource (scanner) is to call this:

```
rc = DSMident(_appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDg.Control, TwDat.Identity, TwMsg.UserSelect, _srcds);
```

I tested this code and it works. But when doing this, a dialog with a listbox appears. I want my own listbox without an `AccessViolationException`. How  can I achieve this?

The documentation found here http://www.twain.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/TWAIN-2.1-Spec.pdf 
says that I should just save my datasource and open it in acquire (page 111)

Code to mess around with can be found here:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner